# i want to retrieve firebase database data with the child value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
query.once("value") .then(function(snapshot) {
      var childData = snapshot.val().user_name;
      var childData2 = snapshot.val().user_id;
 document.writeln(childData);
 document.writeln("\n");
 document.writeln(childData2);
});
```

this is the code i used for retrieving firebase database value using parent value
what changes should i make in this code for retrieving the parent values using the child value

[image: this is my database reference]

I would like to retrieve user_name with help of password.
And also i want it to be work for other records in the users.

Comment: Please read the documentation to understand how to query Firebase Realtime Database using values of children: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the password is `"2110"` you can retrieve the user with:

```
var passwordToLookFor = "2110";
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
var query = ref.orderByChild("password").equalTo(passwordToLookFor);
query.once(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) { // loop over the results
    console.log(child.key);
    console.log(child.val().user_name);
  });
});
```

As Doug commented, please take a moment to read the Firebase documentation on [ordering and querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), as it will save you many questions going forward.